# Struggling with the output of ADC on a PIC18F252

Tags: c, pic, adc

I've recently finished code for a PIC18F252 which uses the built in ADC to convert analogue inputs from 3 sensors into digital outputs that can be sent to motors. The code builds and uploads to the PIC perfectly fine, but unfortunately just doesn't work, and I'm struggling to see where the issue is. 
After testing the output ports for the motors, I've found that they are all outputting the same signal, when they shouldn't be, and it doesn't change depending on the sensors. 
My first thought is that there's something wrong between the output of the ADC (loading the result from ADRESH), and the if statements used to assign a digital value to these outputs. 
I can't upload the entire code as this is coursework, but I've added the relevant parts. I've only included my function for AD conversion using one channel, but the functions for the other two channels are the same, just changing variables.

If anyone is able to spot an issue with this code (presumably around the if statements) I would be grateful!

```
#include <p18F252.h> // PIC specific definitions
#include <xc.h> // Xc8 compiler specifics
#include <stdio.h> // Standard C I/O library
#include <stdlib.h> // Standard C library

// Function declarations
void Config_ADC(void);
void delay(void);
void Motor_Output(unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char z);
void channel3(void);

unsigned char leftSens = 0b00000000; //Initialise left sensor variable

void Config_ADC(void){
    // ADC Setup
    TRISA = 0xFF; // configure port A as inputs
    ADCON1bits.ADFM =0; // left justified
    ADCON1bits.PCFG3=0; 
    ADCON1bits.PCFG2=1;
    ADCON1bits.PCFG1=0; 
    ADCON1bits.PCFG0=0; 
    ADCON1bits.ADCS2=0;
    ADCON0bits.ADCS1=1;
    ADCON0bits.ADCS0=0; 
    ADCON0bits.ADON =1; 
}

// Function for a delay of 1ms
void delay(void){ 
    T2CON = 0x49; // start counting from 73
    PR2 = 0x7C; // stop count at 124
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1; // activate timer 2
    while(!PIR1bits.TMR2IF); // wait for timer flag
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0; // stop timer 2
    PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0; // clear flag
}

void channel3(void){
    ADCON0bits.CHS2 = 0; //Channel selection
    ADCON0bits.CHS1 = 1;
    ADCON0bits.CHS0 = 1;
    delay(); // Acquisition time to charge hold capacitor
    ADCON0bits.GO_DONE = 1; // Start Conversion
    while(ADCON0bits.GO_DONE); // Wait for A/D Conversion to complete
    leftSens = ADRESH; // Return result
}

void main(void){
    TRISB = 0x00; // configure Port B as output
    Config_ADC(); // load ADC
    while(1) { //loop forever/
        channel3(); // Call channel 3 conversion
        Motor_Output(leftSens, middleSens, rightSens);
    }
}

// Function to send instructions to motors
void Motor_Output(unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char z){
    int left, middle, right;
    if(x >= 173){left = 1;}   //173 chosen as threshold 8 bit value
    else if(x < 173){left = 0;}
    else if(y >= 173){middle = 1;}
    else if(y < 173){middle = 0;}
    else if(z >= 173){right = 1;}
    else if(z < 173){right = 0;}

    unsigned char output;
    output = (left << 2) | (middle << 1) | right;  //Bit shifted variables into one value
    switch(output){
        case 0x0:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0; //Test for each output and activate motors accordingly
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        case 0x1:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;
        case 0x2:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        case 0x3:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 0;
        case 0x4:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 1; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        case 0x5:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        case 0x6:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 1; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1;
        case 0x7:
            PORTBbits.RB7 = 0; 
            PORTBbits.RB6 = 1;
            PORTBbits.RB5 = 0;
            PORTBbits.RB4 = 1; 
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: every `case`needs a `break;`

Comment: you don't do anything with `middleSens` and `rightSens`

Comment: And please indent your code, it' really hard to read

Comment: I explained in the question I can't upload the entire code, but middleSens and rightSens are derived the same way leftSens is, using a different channel

Comment: Try to use the bits in LATB as output.

Answer (score 1):

Without going any deeper in analysis there are two major problems:

1. The `if`-`else if`-chain will do just *one* assigment to `left`. To make that obvious I have indented your source this way without any other changes:

   ```
   if (x >= 173) {     // Either THIS...
       left = 1;
   } else
       if (x < 173) {  // Or THAT will be true.
           left = 0;
       } else          // None of the following is executed therefore.
           if (y >= 173) {
               middle = 1;
           } else
               if (y < 173) {
                   middle = 0;
               } else
                   if (z >= 173) {
                       right = 1;
                   } else
                       if (z < 173) {
                           right = 0;
                       }
   ```

   So `middle` and `right` will have undefined values.
2. All your `case`s in the `switch` are missing a `break`. So only the last case or none at all will be executed. Why "none"? Because `middle` and `right` have undefined values, resulting in a random value in `output`.

   *Note: "Random" might be always the same value, depending on the bits set or reset at the locations of `middle` and `right`, respectively.*

Comment: I've fixed the breaks in the cases now, but I'm confused how the if statements only execute the first two? Can you not chain if/else if like that?

Comment: Sure, you can, but most probably it does not implement the logic you want. Just as an exercise: Think about which branches are taken under different conditions. Hints are in my source comments and indentation.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: Is it by design that you are falling through your switch-cases?

```
void Motor_Output(unsigned char x, unsigned char y, unsigned char z){
 // ...
switch(output){
 case 0x0:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x1:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x2:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x3:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x4:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x5:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x6:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 case 0x7:
  ... <-- no break, will continue to execute next case
 }
return;
}
```

Comment: No thats not by design thats just me overlooking it, I'll sort that out and test it again, but would that be the reason that all my outputs end up being the same? For example, there are no cases here where all outputs are 1, but I keep getting all outputs at 1 when I test with a multimeter.

Comment: Do you switch your output to digital with `ANSEL`register?

Comment: As far as I can tell Port B is just digital. On the pinout they're not labelled as analog so I'm not sure if ANSEL is necessary

Comment: @Sam a multimeter is usually pretty slow to measure a signal, so if your outputs toggle quickly (e.g. near or above kHz-frequency), the multimeter may not measure them correctly and you may be misled. I would personally be cautious to trust a signal I haven't "seen" on an oscilloscope. Can't say if switch/case fall-through is the problem or not - I can't read much of the code, because it is written at the register abstraction level, and I don't know much about PICs and their registers.

Comment: check `TRISB`register

Comment: @MortenJensen I'm going to start using a logic probe instead seeing as these are digital signals, but when i was using the multimeter it was showing around 5V, which is the input signal. It was fluctuating a bit but it wasn't ever going down near 0V

Comment: @Mike TRISB is set to 0, configured as outputs

Comment: Thats the whole code? The only thing I left out was 2 repeated functions